# How to use Dataset to group by, but entire rows

Tags: apache-spark, dataset

Reading the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44404817/how-to-use-dataset-to-groupby) post I wonder how can we group the a Dataset but with multiple columns.

Like:

```
val test = Seq(("New York", "Jack", "jdhj"),
    ("Los Angeles", "Tom", "ff"),
    ("Chicago", "David", "ff"),
    ("Houston", "John", "dd"),
    ("Detroit", "Michael", "fff"),
    ("Chicago", "Andrew", "ddd"),
    ("Detroit", "Peter", "dd"),
    ("Detroit", "George", "dkdjkd")
  )
```

I would like to get

Chicago, [( "David", "ff"), ("Andrew", "ddd")]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a case class as below

```
case class TestData (location: String, name: String, value: String)
```

Dummy Data

```
val test = Seq(("New York", "Jack", "jdhj"),
    ("Los Angeles", "Tom", "ff"),
    ("Chicago", "David", "ff"),
    ("Houston", "John", "dd"),
    ("Detroit", "Michael", "fff"),
    ("Chicago", "Andrew", "ddd"),
    ("Detroit", "Peter", "dd"),
    ("Detroit", "George", "dkdjkd")
  )
//change each row to TestData object 
    .map(x => TestData(x._1, x._2, x._3))
    .toDS() // create dataset from above data
```

Output as you require

```
test.groupBy($"location")
    .agg(collect_list(struct("name", "value")).as("data"))
    .show(false)
```

Output:

```
+-----------+--------------------------------------------+
|location   |data                                        |
+-----------+--------------------------------------------+
|Los Angeles|[[Tom,ff]]                                  |
|Detroit    |[[Michael,fff], [Peter,dd], [George,dkdjkd]]|
|Chicago    |[[David,ff], [Andrew,ddd]]                  |
|Houston    |[[John,dd]]                                 |
|New York   |[[Jack,jdhj]]                               |
+-----------+--------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I have suggested a `case class` way in [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44404817/how-to-use-dataset-to-groupby) that you have provided in the question. Here's something different.

**RDD way**

You can simply do the following

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(test)      //creating rdd from test
val resultRdd = rdd.groupBy(x => x._1)              //grouping by the first element
  .mapValues(x => x.map(y => (y._2, y._3)))  //collecting the second and third element in the grouped datset
```

`resultRdd.foreach(println)` should give you

```
(New York,List((Jack,jdhj)))
(Houston,List((John,dd)))
(Chicago,List((David,ff), (Andrew,ddd)))
(Detroit,List((Michael,fff), (Peter,dd), (George,dkdjkd)))
(Los Angeles,List((Tom,ff)))
```

**Converting rdd to dataframe**

If you require output in table format you can just call .toDF() after some manipulation as

```
val df = resultRdd.map(x => (x._1, x._2.toArray)).toDF()
```

`df.show(false)` should give you

```
+-----------+--------------------------------------------+
|_1         |_2                                          |
+-----------+--------------------------------------------+
|New York   |[[Jack,jdhj]]                               |
|Houston    |[[John,dd]]                                 |
|Chicago    |[[David,ff], [Andrew,ddd]]                  |
|Detroit    |[[Michael,fff], [Peter,dd], [George,dkdjkd]]|
|Los Angeles|[[Tom,ff]]                                  |
+-----------+--------------------------------------------+
```